# How can I create a function that check boolean field in array of object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, iteration

**The final goal:** if all the field are `true` the last object.field must change to `true`

```
const badges = [

  { name: "peter", given : true, points: 10 },
    { name: "Alice", given : true,  points: 100 },
    { name: "Hugo", given: true,  points: 100 },
    { name: "Salah", given: false,  points: 500 },
    { name: "Rui", given: false, points: 1000 },
    { name: "Jimena", given: false,  points: 10000 }

]
```

**My code:**

```js
const badges = [
    { name: "peter", given : true, points: 10 },
    { name: "Alice", given : true,  points: 100 },
    { name: "Hugo", given: true,  points: 100 },
    { name: "Salah", given: false,  points: 500 },
    { name: "Rui", given: false, points: 1000 },
    { name: "Jimena", given: false,  points: 10000 }
]

let count = 0
badges.forEach((ele, index) => {
  const l = badges.length
  ele.given === true ? count = count + 1 : count
  count == l - 1 ? badges[l - 1].given = true : badges[l - 1].given
})

console.log(badges)
```

**What I would like to achieve:** is a more generic function that can works anywhere but I could not find the way or maybe a simplest way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work so long as the `field` provided is a boolean. Makes use of `slice` to get everything but the last element and `every` to check all those conform to a condition.

```js
const badges = [

  { name: "peter", given : true, points: 10 },
    { name: "Alice", given : true,  points: 100 },
    { name: "Hugo", given: true,  points: 100 },
    { name: "Salah", given: true,  points: 500 },
    { name: "Rui", given: true, points: 1000 },
    { name: "Jimena", given: false,  points: 10000 }

]

function check(input, field) {
  var result = input.slice(0,input.length-1).every(x => x[field]);
  if(result) {
    badges[input.length-1][field] = true;
  }
}

check(badges,"given");
console.log(badges)
```

Comment: I am trying to understand better your code,  please can you tell me if **x[field]** and **x.field**is the same in this case? and why when I do a `console.log(badges[input.length-1][field])` inside a function it's have a different value from doing it out side?thanks

Comment: Yes `x.field` and `x["field"]` are the same, although the latter allows you to reference the field using a string (see "square bracket notation"). Your second question is unclear. Do you mean before or after calling `check` in this example? That method is updating a value

Comment: you mean `badges[index][field]`? if I use it out side the function scope it's not working, I m just trying to understand the code to use it in another function in the future, do you have any link to information to understand better how to use iteration in array of objects?.@jamiec

Comment: @foxDev https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation might help you understand